# $\mathbb C$ over the field $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ over the field $\mathbb C$

Tags: normed-spaces

> When we talk about the topology of the complex plane what type of $\mathbb C$ as a normed linear space we get concerned about viz. $\mathbb C$ over the field $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ over the field $\mathbb C$ as a Normed Linear Space$?$

ADDED: When we consider $\mathbb C$ as NLS over which field we consider it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them will give you the same topology. The norm in $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is the same as the norm of $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$. By this I mean that as a metric space they are isometric. Therefore they have the same topology.

Comment: When we consider $\mathbb C$ as NLS over which field we consider it?

Comment: Usually we consider $\mathbb{C}.$ But that not because of the norm but because of the Inner product from which the norm is coming.